# AWS EB creates a Security Group with open port 80

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

we create an Single Elastic Beanstalk Instance with own vpc and security group with eb cli (eb create ...). But aws create also an security group with port 22 and 80 open. (0.0.0.0 tcp 80/ 0.0.0.0 tcp 22)
Is there any way to disable the creation of the new security group per cli or delete these (AWS Console or EC2 SDK is no option!)?

Thx

Comment: What command are you using?

Comment: Hi, the command ist `eb create $name -c $CNAME --single --vpc.ec2subnets subnet-...,subnet-... --vpc.id vpc-...  --vpc.securitygroups sg-... --vpc.elbpublic`

Comment: What is the name/description of the security group created?

Comment: The Name is like $name, see `eb create $name ...` description is `VPC Security Group`, and the group name starts with `awseb-e-3sf9srw`

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=151163

Comment: @Mark B: It doesn't work - i still have a inbound rule with 0.0.0.0 tcp port 80?

Comment: It does what it said it would do, which is prevent the port 22 rule. But you would still need to remove the port 80 rule. I think the easiest way to handle this is going to be just writing a quick CLI script to remove those rules.